# I am getting issue of Missing "code verifier"

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, next.js, identityserver4, next-auth

We are working on one of our projects with next.js v12.0.10 and next-auth v3.29.3. While we are doing login, we are redirecting to our other project having an Identity server with react.js.

After entering credentials and successfully authentication, we are redirected back to our main website's error page with options "Try signing in with a different account." and "Sign in with Haymarket Account". When we are doing this process in browser guest mode, mostly every time we can see error page.

If we click on "Sign in with XXX Account" or open the website in a new tab, it successfully logins.

The error is: `Missing code_verifier`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Can't tell much without seeing your next-auth configuration, but the error `Missing code_verifier` is related your provider requirement for "checks". Look it up on next-auth docs here: https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/rest-api#getpost-apiauthcallbackprovider

If you are trying to make custom async requests inside your provider, you may need to send as query params both `grant_type` and `code_verifier`.

Your value for `grant_type` should be `'authorization_code'`.

Your `code_verifier` value is in the request context (`context.checks.code_verifier`)